# org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ULTIMOID"] not found

Tags: java, json, asp.net-web-api

I find myself returning in java a query made through Oracle with the max function.

```
public IEnumerable<Cliente> lastRegister()
        {
            List < Cliente > ultimo = new List<Cliente>();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string query = "select max(Idcliente) as ultimoID from cliente";
            dt = bd.ExecuteQuery(query);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow x in dt.Rows)
                {
                    Cliente c = new Cliente();
                    c._idCliente = int.Parse(x["ULTIMOID"].ToString());
                    ultimo.Add(c);
                }
            }
            return ultimo;
       }
```

I find myself working with web api in C #, which is my controller and connection. Then I make a query with an oracle MAX function and it brings me the data correctly from C #.

The problem started when I want to consume the method that returns the last ID inserted in the web part that is JAVA, but it brings me errors.

Try the method in the POSTMAN and if it works, I don't know if you should bring me all the attributes of the class.

```java
public List<Cliente> lastCliente(){
        globalURL +="/ultimo";
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = Conectar(globalURL);
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP Error code : "+ conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
            String output;
            String jsonRespuesta="";

            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                jsonRespuesta=output;
            }
            JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonRespuesta);
            List<Cliente> xl = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

            for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e = json.getJSONObject(i);
                int lastID = e.getInt("ULTIMOID"); // IT TELLS ME THAT IT DOES NOT FIND THE ULTIMOID OBJECT.
                xl.add(new Cliente(lastID));
            }
            return xl;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.getLogger(ClienteDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Here I leave the exception that I entered after reading the jsonobject.

```
Grave:   org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ULTIMOID"] not found.
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:454)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getInt(JSONObject.java:514)
```

This gives me the api web method.

[image]

Comment: I think the error message is very clear. Field `ULTIMOID` doesn't exist in the response JSON string.

Comment: @LHCHIN 
In the end I worked working with cursor and subquery.